# Passing detectDates=TRUE to read.xlsx in lapply

Tags: r, excel, date, lapply

I'm working with quite a large number of different files, so I'd like to read them in with a loop. It works fine for csv files, but I've encountered an issue when reading in xlsx files.

```
library(openxlsx)
allFiles <- list.files("path", full.names = T) 
allFiles <- lapply(allFiles, read.xlsx)
```

One of the columns in my dataset contains dates, which were automatically converted to a set of strange numbers when I ran the code above. (Other than that, everything worked fine.) So I tried passing another argument to the function:

```
allFiles <- list.files("path", full.names = T) 
allFiles <- lapply(allFiles, read.xlsx, detectDates = TRUE)
```

This returned an error message:

```
Error in file(description = xlsxFile) : invalid 'description' argument
```

It worked fine though when I tried it on a single file:

```
read.xlsx("path", detectDates = TRUE)
```

Furthermore, strangely enough, when I then removed the argument and tried to run

```
allFiles <- list.files("path", full.names = T) 
allFiles <- lapply(allFiles, read.xlsx)
```

which had worked before, it returned the same error (invalid 'description' argument). A few hours later, after I'd shut down and restarted RStudio, it worked again. When I tried the detectDates = TRUE argument, the process repeated itself, and now the loop works neither with nor without it. 
I've read in some online discussions that XLConnect helps sometimes with things like this, but unfortunately I'm unable to load it (it requires rJava, which returns an error when I try to load it even though I installed it successfully).

It would take ages to read in every file individually or convert to csv. Has anyone encountered this before or knows a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following call to `lapply()`:

```
allFiles <- lapply(allFiles, read.xlsx, detectDates = TRUE)
```

I believe that you are actually passing `detectDates = TRUE` as an argument to `lapply` but not `read.xlsx`.  You can rephrase your call as follows:

```
allFiles <- lapply(allFiles, function(x) read.xlsx(x, detectDates = TRUE))
```